# Capturing program output without newline in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have program (flash_erase) that prints it's output to STDOUT, but without newline. This is common method of printing progress.

For example:

```
Erasing 4 Kibyte @ 0 -- 0 % complete
```

And I get new line only when the process finish:

```
Erasing 4 Kibyte @ 1f000 -- 100 % complete
```

I what to pipe the progress to another script. I can replace the \r with \n using tr, but still doesn't work. The output is processed the the program finish.

```
flash_erase /dev/mtd1 0 0 | tr '\r' '\n' | while read line; do
    some_program $line;
done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose tr only sees the whole output once the newline is emitted. Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe helps

Comment: Well no, because after tr the output is split into separate lines. I think the problem is with the output from tr.

Comment: If you're lucky `stdbuf` may be able to help.  Try something like `stdbuf -o0 flash_erase /dev/mtd1 0 0` ... look at the man-page for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with:

```
flash_erase /dev/mtd1 0 0 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\r' '\n' | while read -r line; do
    something $line
done
```